# What format does an array need to be in order for a spinner to use it properly?

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, spinner

I have a spinner in my app that should be populated with a list of suppliers. The spinner originally came from some example code and works perfectly using the fixed strings in the example. However, in my case, I get my list of values (suppliers) from an API. I can see the API being called correctly and the data returned in Logcat. I want to get the data from this response and use it as the object list for my spinner.

My question is two fold. Is there a more direct way of translating the response to the adapter, and if not, how do I translate reading the response into something the spinner will use?

My intent code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddNewSupplier">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSupplierName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Supplier Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinSelectSupplier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/lblSupplierName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/txtSupplierName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/lblSupplierName" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The class is:

```
class AddNewSupplier : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var lblSupplierName: TextView
    private lateinit var spinSelectSupplier: Spinner

    var aSups: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    var strSups: String = ""
    var arrSuppliers = arrayOf("")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_supplier)

    lblSupplierName = findViewById(R.id.lblSupplierName)

    spinSelectSupplier = findViewById(R.id.spinSelectSupplier)

    loadSupplierList()

    var list_of_items = arrayOf(strSups)

    if (spinSelectSupplier != null) {
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_of_items)
        spinSelectSupplier.adapter = adapter
        spinSelectSupplier.onItemSelectedListener = object :
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>,
                                        view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Log.d("Seld: ", aSups[position].toString())
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                // write code to perform some action
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun loadSupplierList() {
    AllSuppliers.create().getAllSuppliers("all").enqueue(object : Callback<SupplierList> {

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<SupplierList>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Error :: ", t.localizedMessage!!)
            t.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<SupplierList>,
            response: Response<SupplierList>
        ) {
            Log.d("AllSuppliers :: ", response.body().toString())
            val suppliers = response.body()?.APIResult!![0]

            for (i in 0..suppliers.suppliers.size - 1) {
                Log.d("Each: ", suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name)

                aSups.add(suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name)
                strSups += ", \"" + suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name + "\""
            }
            strSups = strSups.subSequence(1, strSups.length).toString()
            Log.d("StrArr:", strSups)
            Log.d("ArrElem:", aSups[1].toString())
        }
    })
  }
}
```

The API being called to get the suppliers returns 3 suppliers and I can see each one in the loop so I know the response has been fully returned at this point.

I have tried appending the supplier to the array aSup and this doesn't work for the spinner (the spinner is null) although I can read element 1 happily. I even tried building a string (list_of_items) giving me "supplier 1", "supplier 2" etc as this is the same as the working example that I took the code from, but I still get a a null array. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: Hi @timfoster, try to fill the spinner after you called the `loadSupplierList()`. I mean make sure `strSups` is not null. Try to fill the spinner in `onResponse()` method.

Comment: set Adapter for spinner within  onResponse() method.

Comment: Perfect @danialiranpour, that you very much. I've been struggling with this for days! I needed to change the first parameter inside ArrayAdapter, but aside from that 100%. If you add it as a answer, I can accept it as the answer and give you kudos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to fill the spinner after call the `loadSupplierList()`. I mean make sure `strSups` is not null. Try to fill the spinner in `onResponse()` method.
Like this:

```
class AddNewSupplier : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var lblSupplierName: TextView
    private lateinit var spinSelectSupplier: Spinner

    var aSups: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    var strSups: String = ""
    var arrSuppliers = arrayOf("")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_supplier)

    lblSupplierName = findViewById(R.id.lblSupplierName)

    spinSelectSupplier = findViewById(R.id.spinSelectSupplier)

    loadSupplierList()    
   
}

private fun loadSupplierList() {
    AllSuppliers.create().getAllSuppliers("all").enqueue(object : Callback<SupplierList> {

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<SupplierList>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("Error :: ", t.localizedMessage!!)
            t.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<SupplierList>,
            response: Response<SupplierList>
        ) {
            Log.d("AllSuppliers :: ", response.body().toString())
            val suppliers = response.body()?.APIResult!![0]

            for (i in 0..suppliers.suppliers.size - 1) {
                Log.d("Each: ", suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name)

                aSups.add(suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name)
                strSups += ", \"" + suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name + "\""
            }
            strSups = strSups.subSequence(1, strSups.length).toString()
            Log.d("StrArr:", strSups)
            Log.d("ArrElem:", aSups[1].toString())
           
            // call the new method here
            fillSpinner()
        }
    })
  }

  private fun fillSpinner(){

      var list_of_items = arrayOf(strSups)
      if (spinSelectSupplier != null) {
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list_of_items)
        spinSelectSupplier.adapter = adapter
        spinSelectSupplier.onItemSelectedListener = object :
            AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>,
                                        view: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
                Log.d("Seld: ", aSups[position].toString())
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>) {
                // write code to perform some action
            }
        }
    }      


  }

}
```